# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in ReactJS when iterate

Tags: reactjs

In response I get `json`

How can I display each `version`?

I get error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
data:
name: "Google Chrome"
versions: Array(7)
0: "1.0.1"
1: "1.0.2"
2: "1.0.3"
3: 1
4: "asas"
5: "dasdasd"
6: "asdasdasdasdasd"
```

**JS**

```
class AppDetail extends Component {
    state = {
        app: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/')
        .then(response => this.setState({ app: response.data }))

    render() {
        return (
            <div>


                {this.state.app.versions.map((version) => {
                    return (<p> key={version.???}>{version.???}</a></p>)
                })}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the initial state is an empty array `app: []`, and when you do `app.versions` it's undefined.

Change it to

```
state = {
    app: {
       name: '',
       versions: []
    }
}
```

And because it's an array of strings, when doing `versions.map((version) =>`, `version` will be the string, so you can just render it.

Here is the full code

```
class AppDetail extends Component {

    state = {
        app: {
           name: '',
           versions: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/')
        .then(response => this.setState({ app: response.data }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.app.versions.map((version) => {
                    return (<p> key={version}>{version}</a></p>)
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `app` state does not have `versions` variable. So you have to update state as below.

```
    state = {
        app: {
           name: null,
           versions: []
        }
    }
```

It will be good to check variable before proceed.

```
{this.state.app && Array.isArray(this.state.app.versions) && this.state.app.versions.map((version) => {
     return (<p> key={version.???}>{version.???}</a></p>)
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before map, try to check whether `this.state.app.versions` is available or not as below:

```
class AppDetail extends Component {
    state = {
        app: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/')
        .then(response => this.setState({ app: response.data }))

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                {this.state.app.versions && this.state.app.versions.map((version) => {
                    return (<p> key={version.???}>{version.???}</a></p>)
                })}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```